# Memory Still Valid?

Tags: c++

I have a  C++ class defined as
[image]

Now, assume that I am newing up the memory of the map sessionConnections in the constructor itself.
My question is that pointer value of connCtx stored in the map of m_sessionConnections will be always there and not go out of scope, once it is returned from the function. I am seeing that when in the other function, I am using the ierator to get the value of connCtx, it is sometimes coming as some dangling pointer.

Comment: Next time, just copy-and-paste the code into your question instead of taking a screenshot then uploading it.

Comment: Wow, a screenshot of source code!  Would you mind printing it out and taking a photo of it placed on a [wooden table](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Web_0_0x2e_1.aspx)?  But seriously, please post your source code **as text**.

Comment: @Brajesh: Also, [see this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/19/8877486.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the strong critic! Next time, try to answer the question as well..

Answer (score 2):

If you allocate memory on the heap (with `new`) then it is valid until you explicitly `delete` it.